# Using a resistor in series toreduce the voltage supplied to an appliance / microwave bulb

Tags: resistors

I just want to reduce the voltage supplied to a appliance microwave bulb from 125 v supply to about 110-115 volt. The bulb that I bought is rated at 120 v and the supply pins / connection supply 125 v. The bulb may blow sooner than necessary. 
What size resistor in series do I use? And is this necessary to do?

Comment: just get a lower power rated bulb, it will amount to the same thing.  A Resistor is a poor solution. The power resistor will cost more than a bulb or just use the dim setting

Comment: Thanks. But I already bought the bulb. I can probably pull a resistor from an old dimmer switch and / or electrical part of some sort.

Comment: is too bright? or too hot? was it expensive?

Comment: is too bright? or too hot? was it expensive?  Line voltage is always 10% tolerance and bulbs are designed to operate with this.  The only catch is designers forget to provide air circulation to prevent thermal rise and this cuts incandescent lifetime in half for every 10deg'C rise above designed life of 2000~3000h at rated power.  Since they operate around 2800'C on the filament,  it's pretty easy to to reduce and extend the life by modification of surface temp. with a small enclosed space and no vent.

Comment: If you used another bulb as a resistor use one with higher rating like 4x 8W=32W to reduce total power 10% Like a halogen PAR lamp or whatever.  We had one of those silver dome coated 150W bulbs.  THe parabolic reflector worked into a swag lamp so all the heat wentup and the bulb was relatively cool. But the swag lamp was very bright.  It lasted for about 15 yrs.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to increase lifetime of an incandescent bulb is to put a diode in series with it. In this case, a 1N4004 or higher. The bulb, of course, will be dimmer, but that's why it will last longer.